# JQuery - Reloading a Div and Calling an API On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm building a random quote generator web app, and I'm able to call an API using JQuery, then use the returned JSON data to print out a quote. I've implemented a button to attempt to call the API for another quote, and which calls the **getJSON function**, but doesn't get new JSON data.

The full code is on CodePen: http://codepen.io/oscarwong67/pen/eZLQLz

Here's what I use to get the Quote:

```
var getQuote = function() {
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1" + "?callback?", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    $("#quote").html(json[0].content);  
    $("#speaker").html("- " + json[0].title);
  });
}

getQuote(); //called when the page initially loads

$("#new-quote").on("click", function() {
  getQuote();
});
```

And here's the relevant HTML that it changes:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 text-center" id="quote-div">
      <p id="quote">Loading Your Quote</p>
      <p id="speaker"></p>
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="new-quote">New Quote!</button>
</div>
```

The function is called when the page initially loads, and will call on the button click, but the JSON returned DOES NOT change.

Comment: The problem is that your result of $.getJSON is cached. Use $.ajax with cache: false option or stay with $.getJSON and use $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }) before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getJSON has an issue with caching. You need to set the cache: false. Just do that and you code works fine.

To set cache:false there are a number of ways. Two possible ways are:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

and

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true});
$.getJSON("/url",function(data,item) {
     // do stuff with callback data
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
   });
```

Your final JS:

```
var getQuote = function() {
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1" + "?callback?", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    $("#quote").html(json[0].content);  
    $("#speaker").html("- " + json[0].title);
    $("#speaker").css('text-align', "right");
    $("#speaker").css('padding-right', "2%");
    $("#speaker").css('font-size', "16pt");
    $("#speaker").css('font-weight', "bold");
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  });
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNOqWj)